# Need a simple T-SQL Query

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2012

I have the following table:

```
PrimaryKeyColumn1 |PrimaryKeyColumn2 |   Column_A | Column_B | Column_C|
ID1                     Key1                 0           1         0
ID2                     Key2                 1           0         1      
ID3                     Key3                 1           1         0
```

Basically, I need to figure out a T-SQL query to get the results like this:

```
ID1 Key1 B
ID2 Key2 A,C
ID3 Key3 A,B
```

Can someone please help me figure this out? The name of the columns include the letter (A,b,c...z) at the end of the column name after a underscore. The 0 or 1 indicates if that letter applies to the ID or not. If 0 it means not and if 1 it means yes. so, it needs to be next to the id in the results if it is 1 otherwise not needed if it is 0.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the easiest way is just to use `CASE` and some string logic:

```
select PrimaryKeyColumn1, PrimaryKeyColumn2,
       stuff(((case when column_a = 1 then ',A' else '' end) +
              (case when column_b = 1 then ',B' else '' end) +
              (case when column_c = 1 then ',C' else '' end)
             ), 1, 1, '') as vals
from . . .
```

Comment: thank you, it says Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'values'.

Comment: Just change `values` to the column alias you prefer. `values` is a keyword/reserved word. You could also put it in quotes or square braces.

Answer (score 1):

i've done something like this

```
    CREATE TABLE #test
    (
        primaryKey nvarchar(150)
        , columnA bit
        , columnB bit
        , columnC bit
    ) -- create some test table

    INSERT INTO #test
    VALUES 
    ('ID1',1,0,0)
    ,('ID2',1,1,0)
    ,('ID3',1,0,1) -- as well as the test values

    SELECT
        *
    into #tmpUnpiv
    FROM #test
    UNPIVOT
    (
        truefalse
        for columnName in (columnA, columnB, columnC)
    ) unpiv; -- save the un-pivoted result as new table #tmpUnpiv

    SELECT
        DISTINCT
            primaryKey + ' ' + (SELECT replace(columnName,'column','') + ',' AS [text()]  from #tmpUnPiv WHERE primaryKey = p.primaryKey AND truefalse = 1 FOR XML PATH(''))
    FROM #tmpUnPiv p -- then combine results through XML PATH

    DROP TABLE #tmpUnPiv
    DROP TABLE #test
    -- drop temp tables
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this (untested)

```
;with cte as
(
select *
from yourtable
cross apply (values ('A',ColumnA),
                    ('B',ColumnB),
                    ('C',ColumnC)) CS (name,value)
Where cs.value <> 0 
)
SELECT a.PrimaryKeyColumn,
       LEFT(cs.result, Len(cs.result) - 1) AS result                           
FROM   cte a
       CROSS APPLY (SELECT value + ','
                    FROM   cte B
                    WHERE  a.PrimaryKeyColumn = b.PrimaryKeyColumn
                    FOR XML PATH('')) cs (result)
GROUP  BY a.PrimaryKeyColumn,
          LEFT(cs.result, Len(cs.result) - 1)
```

Comment: sorry, I forgot, there are composite primarily keys. So I have PrimaryKeyColumn1 and PrimaryKeyColumn2 in my table.

Comment: @user3314399 - Then you need to add it in `cross apply` where clause

Comment: sorry what is a cross apply? I modifed the table. Can you please have a look

Comment: Gordon's answer is a much simpler approach especially if you don't know what's going on with the `cross apply`. It's worth learning about but probably overkill for a straightforward result like this one.